# Java TCP server received every line from Client when all of them are sent

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, flush

I wrote two small java programs: a TCP client which sends many lines of data from a txt file, and a TCP Server which accepts connection and receives line by line.

It works, but Server receives all the lines together, when transmission is over and client closes the socket. I don't understand why, because I'm using flush after each line sent into the Client, and I always thought that was to avoid this kind of situation.

If my test.txt file contents the numbers 1 2 3 ... 10, each one in a new line, Server's output is: "12345678910" and then in a new line it writes in console "null".

Server code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ServidorTCP {

  private String HOST;
  static final int PUERTO = 20001;

      public ServidorTCP( ) {
        try{
          ServerSocket skServidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);
              Socket skCliente = skServidor.accept();
          DataInputStream inFromClient = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(skCliente.getInputStream()));

          while(true){
              String lineaLeida = inFromClient.readUTF();
              if(lineaLeida.equals("END")) break;
              System.out.println(lineaLeida);
          }
              inFromClient.close();
              skCliente.close();
          skServidor.close();
          System.out.println( "Transmission ended" );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
          System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        }
      }


      public static void main( String[] arg ) {
        new ServidorTCP();
      }

    }
```

Cliente code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ClienteTCP {

  static final String HOST = "192.168.1.201";
  static final int PUERTO = 20001;

  public ClienteTCP( ) {
    try{
      Socket skCliente = new Socket(HOST, PUERTO);
      if(skCliente.isConnected()) System.out.println("Connected!");
      DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(skCliente.getOutputStream());

      File testFile = new File("test.txt");
      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile));
      String line;
      while((line=input.readLine())!=null) {
        if(!line.endsWith("\n")) line = line + "\n";
        System.out.println("Sending: " + line);
        outToServer.writeBytes(line);
        outToServer.flush();
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
      }
      outToServer.writeBytes("END");
      input.close();
      outToServer.close();
      skCliente.close();
    } catch( Exception e ) {
      System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }
  }


  public static void main( String[] arg ) {
    new ClienteTCP();
  }

}
```

Where is the problem?

EDIT: I have edited the code as suggested. Now doesn't receive anyhing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact of the matter is that your code doesn't work at all, let alone before or after the socket is closed. You are writing with `writeUTF()` and reading with `readLine().` This does not work. You need to:

1. write with `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` and read with `DataInputStream.readUTF()`
2. write with `println()` (supplied by several I/O classes), or `write()` or `print()` (supplied by several I/O classes), followed by `BufferedWriter.newline()`, or
3. write with `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` and read with `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`.

Etc. Writing with one API and reading with a non-symmetrical API doesn't work.

Comment: The reason for that is that I tried to use 'DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())', and when compiling it says it's deprecated :|

What should I use then?

Comment: I'm using now 'DataInputStream inFromClient = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(skCliente.getInputStream()))' and then 'String lineaLeida = inFromClient.readUTF()'. The problem still happens

Comment: @RomanRdgz Hard to believe, but another problem is that you are closing the socket when you should be closing `outToServer`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but might it be possible that the BufferedInputStream is the problem? This might delay the incoming data such that it is read all at once.

Comment: @denahiro No. `BufferedInputStream` will read and buffer whatever data is available to be read when its `read()` method is called, blocking until at least one byte is available. That's the general contract of all `InputStreams`.

Comment: @EJP Closing the socket is not a problem since I'm not usign it anymore. It's true I should also close outToServer, but anyway the program is finishing. Hard to beliebe or not, I'm still having the same problem

Comment: @RomanRdgz Closing the socket instead of the output stream wrapped around the socket output stream *is* a problem, because it's the wrong thing to do. In this case it is benign, as `DataOutputStream` isn't buffered, but in general you must close the outermost output stream you have wrapped around the socket, to ensure the final `flush().` What you are doing is poor practice. Closing either the input stream or the output stream closes the socket. Regarding persistence of your problem I suggest you post your current code, NB via editing it into your question.

Comment: @EJP also tried DataInputStream inFromClient = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(skCliente.getInputStream())); and same results

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with reading or writing (or at least not explicitly). The problem is your string. `input.readLine()` removes the `end of line` which means the string you're sending is just the number. On the server side then you receive a lot of strings but `inFromClient.readLine()` waits until it gets an `end of line` which never arrives until the stream closes and sends an `end of file`.

Just add an `end of line` to every string you're sending and it should work.

Comment: I have tried to add a \n to the end of each line I'm sending, but still happens the same in the receiving side